# Installing Android Studio on Mac OSX 10.12 fails to install android sdk

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I want to do some android development.

I have a new macbook, on Mac OSX version `10.12.6`

I go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html and download version `3.0.0.18` for the mac of Android Studio.

The download completes, I drag the app into my Applications Folder, and run.

Android Studio then shows this error:
[image]

This says the Android SDK is not found -- which is true I don't have one installed.

I click next and am shown this screen - which is where I find the problem:
[image]

The box on this screen says `Android SDK - (installed)` which is strange because the Android SDK is *not* installed. The screen suggests the android SDK location is /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk however this directory does not exist on my machine.

I click Next, then Finish and am presented with this screen:

[image]

Can somebody please help me -- Android Studio should download for me the SDK if I don't have one installed so why does it believe I have one when I don't?

Comment: Have you downloaded the the android sdk..?

Comment: Create a folder (anywhere, I have it in `~/dev/sdk`) and point it there. The folder must exist.

Comment: Are you saying I should make the folder and point it there? Pointing that at an empty folder makes no difference - it still says "SDK does not exist" and it doesn't download it. Yash786 you ask have i downloaded the SDK, the answer is no, because Android Studio should do that for me no?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I am having the same issue

Comment: anon -- yes - my answer below is how i fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here was a firewall blocking the outbound call to the download server, which was not reported correctly from the Android Studio.

Trying the install from a different location worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you should run application behind proxy, pretty weird huh?
I had this problem when i clone repo with git desktop and same issue as you had.
First of all find a proxy.

```
https://hidemy.name/tr/proxy-list/?type=h#list
```

For git desktop you have to change your git config proxy:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.mycompany:80
```

So now you can clone with github desktop app.

And for Android Studio when you get Android Studio First Run dialog box click Setup Proxy and enter proxy and it will be fine.